# Modal BootStrap não consegue pegar variável asp de codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, bootstrap, variáveis, modal

Caros, bom dia!

Estou iniciando e apanhando muito em minha primeira oportunidade como programador rsrs

Em MinhasVendas2.aspx tenho

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- dialog body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        Forma de Pagamento

        <%--  <%# Eval("desc_tp_pagamento") %>
          teste--%>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

         Dados Pagto: <%=id_imobiliaria_pagamento%>
            <label id="lblteste"></label>


      </div>
      <!-- dialog buttons -->
      <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" id="a.btn" class="btn btn-primary"data-dismiss="modal">OK</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            <%--#modalformapagto fim--%>
```

aqui o script que está sendo disparado via codebehind:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function myModal() {

                    $("#myModal").modal();

                    $("#myModal").on("show", function () {    // wire up the OK button to dismiss the modal when shown
                        $("#myModal a.btn").on("click", function (e) {
                            console.log("button pressed");   // just as an example...
                            $("#myModal").modal('hide');     // dismiss the dialog
                        });
                    })
                };
                    function myModalHide() {
                        $("#myModal").on("hide", function () {    // remove the event listeners when the dialog is dismissed
                            $("#myModal a.btn").off("click");
                        })
                    };

                    function myModalHidden() {
                        $("#myModal").on("hidden", function () {  // remove the actual elements from the DOM when fully hidden
                            $("#myModal").remove();
                        });

                        $("#myModal").modal({                    // wire up the actual modal functionality and show the dialog
                            "backdrop": "static",
                            "keyboard": true,
                            "show": true                     // ensure the modal is shown immediately
                        })
                    }
                ;
</script>
```

e aqui o codbehind

```
public void gdvPagamentos_SelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            List<pagamento> pagto = new List<pagamento>();
            var id_imobiliaria_pagamento = gdvPagamentos.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;


            //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "", "myModal();", true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
                 (Page,
                  this.GetType(),
                  "script",
                  "myModal();",
                  true);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){ }
    }
```

declarei a variavel id_imobiliaria_pagamento tambem fora do metodo e o dado é recuperado normal no codebehind.

Mas essa mesma variável, com o modal aberto, e chamada no código html dentro do modal, não mostra nada.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: bem vindo ao stackoverflow, essa sua resposta faz parte da sua pergunta?, clique em `Editar` a sua pergunta (canto inferior esquerdo)e coloque o código nela.

Comment: foi errado rsrs

Comment: Obrigado! Então, estou apanhando por não conseguir fazer o modal quando aberto puxar o valor dessa variável aí... no aguardo de sugestões... vlw!!!

Answer (score 0):

No codebehind, dentro do método eu havia declarado a variável de uma forma (exemplo var xxxxx) e fora do método eu havia definido como string... com isso tava ocorrendo o problema de não exibição da mesma... Estranho que não acusava erro. Corrigi para string tb dentro do método e o conteúdo das variáveis passou a ser apresentado.